# How do you log an int on Android?

Tags: android, logging

I'm logging this:

```
Log.d(getClass().getName(), "BLA BLA BLA");
```

How can I show an `int` value? What is the equivalent of C's `%d`?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use string concatenation:

```
Log.d(getClass().getName(), "value = " + intVar);
```

or more flexibly (and similar to c-style printf) you can use Java's `String.format()`:

```
Log.d(getClass().getName(), String.format("value = %d", intVar));
```

Answer (score 6):

```
String.valueOf()
```

is what you need if you want string representations of various objects.

And by the way, I'd recommend using [slf4j for Android](http://www.slf4j.org/android/). This way, you don't have to pass class name as the first parameter every single time.

Answer (score 3):

or you could use

```
Integer.toString(intVar);
```

Assuming `intVar` is an `Integer` and not the primitive `int`.

Answer (score 1):

```
   Log.i("value entered", Float.toString(finalValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

Android's logging does not support formatted printf style string natively. Usually you just use valueOf or toString and use string concats, though if you must you can always use the [Formatter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

Answer (score 0):

First Import Log; 
import android.util.Log;

Then Create Method & check this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.e("Check","We are in Resume");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.e("Check","We are in Pause");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.e("Check","We are in Stop");
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.e("Check","We are in Destroy");
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.e("Check","We are in Star");
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    Log.e("Check","We are in ReStar");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Locale to avoid extra locale warnings -

```
Log.d(getClass().getName(), String.format(Locale.US, "value = %d", intVar));
```